# Django StackedInline does not work in CmsPlugin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

In my CMS adminpanel I have an inline for a CmsPlugin in Django.

Here is the code:

```
class MyEntryInLine(StackedInline):
    model = MyRelatedModel
    extra = 2

class MyCmsPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = MyPluginModel
    render_template = "cms_plugins/my_template.html"

    inlines = [MyEntryInLine,]
```

The `add_view` works well.

However, the `change_view` does not show me the inlines()...

It seems to be a bug or a limit of django-cms.

Django Version = (1, 4, 5, 'final', 0)

DjangoCMS Version = '2.3.5'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault.
It was an unicode error of "MyPluginModel" that failed silently (why silently?)

Comment: Unfortunately it fails silently because some plugins might come from third party apps and if they had an error, we wouldn't want to completely block you from continuing with your app. However some nice warning would be nice. As a rule of thumb, anytime a plugin does not show up, get on the django shell ./manage.py shell and run from myapp.cms_plugins import * , doing that will save you lots of debugging time :)

Comment: Hi madeng84, what was your error? I'm having a similar problem and I can't find out why.
Also whn I do the import thing in the shell there are no errors.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi mantish, excuse me but i'm reading this answer only now.
In the __unicode__ function was called a not existing attribute of the CMSPlugin class. For example i wrote self.tilte instead of self.title.. 
Good Luck :D